# How do I calculate the location of points in a rotated shape AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, trigonometry

I am creating a game in which I draw a series of polygons by creating points around a radius of a cricle.

Later on I rotate the shapes and I need to calculate the new location (X,Y) of the points based on the rotation. I have the Old XY of each point, the XY of the center of the shape, radius of shape and the rotation.

Have a look at my diagram of the problem.

[image: Diagram of problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible to use matrix transformations for this, but you can also do it manually:
http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/2drota.htm

So essentially;

```
newX = initialX * Math.cos(angle) - initialY * Math.sin(angle);
newY = initialY * Math.cos(angle) + initialX * Math.sin(angle);
//Angle is in radians btw
```

This assumes that the initialX/Y is relative to the center of rotation, so you would have to subtract the center point before starting, and then add it again after the calculation to place it correctly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How would you do this if your shape was rotated in 3D space?

Answer (score 1):

For each point do:

```
alpha = arctan2(x, y)
len = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
newX = len * cos(alpha + rotation)
newy = len * sin(alpha + rotation)
```

Original [x,y] and new [newX,newY] coordinates are both relative to the center of your rotation. If your original [x,y] is absolut, you have to calculate relative first:

```
x = xAbs - xCenter
y = yAbs - yCenter
```

Make sure your arctan2 function provides a result of PI/2 or -PI/2 if x=0. Primitive arctan functions do not allow x=0.

Comment: For this you would have to calculate the length of the original point as well, and multiply the results of cos/sin with that, to get the correct position.

Comment: Yes @JonatanHedborg, you are correct. I have edited accordingly, so now it should be correct.